# Validate input boxes against a pattern using jquery and display div incase of error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of text boxes which needs to have input in a certain pattern.
On jquery load, I attach a pattern attribute to each of the text boxes which i am interested in dealing with.
What I am trying to achieve now is when after typing in a text box and losing focus I would like to test against the pattern and display a div which will show an error box if it doesnt match the pattern. I am not able to identify how I should validate the text against the pattern and show the div.

```
<input id="test-1">
<div id="test-1-error"class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<input id="test-2">
<div id="test-2-error" class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<br>
<input id="test-1">
<div id="test-1-error"class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<input id="test-2">
<div id="test-2-error" class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<br>
```

My Jquery

```
 $('[id="test"]').each(function(i, val) {
    $(val).attr("pattern", "(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" );
  });

  $('[id="test"]').focusout(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    //Validate text in pattern
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this snippet

```js
 var regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
  $(".test").keyup(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    var $this = $(this);
     if(!regex.test($this.val())){
     $this.next().show();
    }else{
    $this.next().hide();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test">
<div id="test-1-error"class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div><br>
<input class="test">
<div id="test-2-error" class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<br>
<input class="test">
<div id="test-1-error"class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div><br>
<input class="test">
<div id="test-2-error" class="alert" style="display:none">
  This is an error!
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: my browser freezes when i run your code snippet and press tab to focus away